# Anchor tag generates blank href attribute using echo esc_url( )

Tags: categories, link-category

Following is my categories page. It's listing the all categories in the page.
But when `<a href>` gets blank value here. see the attached screen shot.
Why `href` is blank here

```
 li><a href="<?php echo esc_url(   $category_link ); ?>"><?php echo $cat- >name; ?></a></li>
```

Here the the complete code

```
<? php
    /*
    Template Name: Categories
    */
        get_header(); 
        $cats =  get_categories();
        $num_cats  = wp_count_terms('category'); 
        $count = $num_cats;  // Total Categories
        $linetotal=round($count/3); // Part of Category
        $cat1 = get_query_var('cat');
        $category_link = get_category_link( $cat1 );    
        ?>
        <!-- Main body section begins -->   
    <div class="row">   
      <div class="medium-4 large-4 columns category_list">
        <ul>
            <?php
          $totalcount = 1;
          $totalpart = 1;
          foreach($cats as $cat): ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
            <?php
            if($totalcount % $linetotal == 0 && $totalpart < 3) { 
              echo '</ul></div><div class="medium-4 large-4 columns category_list"><ul>';
                  $totalpart++;
            }
            $totalcount++;
          endforeach;?>
        </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    <?PHP get_footer(); ?>
```

[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What does `$category_link` look like?

Comment: @birgire means? i do not understand the question. `$cat1 = get_query_var('cat');
        $category_link = get_category_link( $cat1 ); `

Comment: I mean, what's the value of `$category_link`?

Comment: It's getting the value from category ID

Comment: I just want to make sure it's not empty. So did you check out `echo $category_link;`?

Comment: thats the issue.. it's echoing nothing.. why? I use the same code on another site. thats working fine there.

Comment: I thought so, the question title is then somewhat misleading, since this isn't `esc_url()` fault ;-) So you need to debug things further up. Try to echo all your variables and see if you can spot where the problem starts.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the template for a category archive, but for a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template) because of this:

```
/*
Template Name: Categories
*/
```

The query variable 'cat' is not set in pages.

Move `get_category_link( $id );` inside the foreach.

```
<li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
```